# Ownerdrawn tray icon (winapi)?

Tags: c++, winapi, taskbar

Is it possible to make an ownerdrawn tray icon using winapi ? ( c++ non-mfc.)

For now im using server generated png -> ico -> tray but this is ugly and slow ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just dynamically create the HICON, no?   Build up the image that you want (or convert from jpg/bmp/png) as a DIB and convert to an HICON.  Use your created icon to send to `Shell_NotifyIcon()`.

Old reference, but it should get you started.   [Icons in Win32.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx)

Comment: yes yes i know i can do that just i wanted to be able to draw the icon myself not update it all the time :) anyway since this will suffice for most ppl and ill probably end up using it i accept this as the answer